# Post give CORS Error, GET Working. Node JS

Tags: node.js, cors

My POST method doesn't work, but my GET method does. Where could I be wrong?

Server JS

```
const Express = require('express');
const App = Express();
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Cors = require('./Others/Cors');
App.use(Cors);
```

Cors Options JS

```
const Cors = require('cors');
let CorsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}
module.exports = Cors(CorsOptions);
```

One Router Page

```
const Express = require('express');
const Router = Express.Router();
const Controller = require('../Controllers/Scenarios');
const Upload = require('../Others/MulterBody');
const Cors = require('../Others/Cors');

Router.get('/Scenarios_GetAll', Controller.GetAll);
Router.post('/Scenarios_ChangeActive', Controller.ChangeActive);
Router.get('/Scenarios_DeleteOne/:id',Controller.DeleteOne);
Router.post('/Scenarios_AddOne', Upload.none(), Controller.AddOne);
Router.post('/Scenarios_UpdateOne', Upload.none(), Controller.UpdateOne);
Router.get('/Scenarios_GetListForGame/:id', Controller.GetListForGame);
module.exports = Router;
```

Comment: can you include the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser devtools console logs, and the network tab, help troubleshoot this kind of stuff.

Try adding this line to your Router definitions, to handle the http OPTIONS verb.

```
Router.options('*', Cors)
```

You may need to refactor your code to make a pure `cors()` method call available to use with `options` though.  Get rid of your Cors Options JS source file and write your router like this.

```
...
const Upload = require('../Others/MulterBody');
const cors = require('cors');
cors({
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    });

Router.options('*', cors());
Router.get('/Scenarios_GetAll', Controller.GetAll);
...
```